# Replicating pandas to_dict in polars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

In pandas I can do the following to get a key/value dictionary from `to_dict`

```
d = [{'key':'a', 'value':1}, {'key':'b', 'value':2}, {'key':'b', 'value':1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.groupby('key')['value'].sum().to_dict()
Out[13]: {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
```

When I attempt to replicate this in polars i get the following:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(d)
In [133]: df.groupby('key').agg(pl.col('value').sum()).to_dict(as_series=False)
Out[133]: {'key': ['a', 'b'], 'value': [1, 3]}

In [134]: df.groupby('key').agg(pl.col('value').sum()).transpose().to_dict(as_series=False)
Out[134]: {'column_0': ['b', '3'], 'column_1': ['a', '1']}
```

Although it's technically correct, unpacking this to the dict that pandas returns for a large dataframe will be slow. How can I have polars return the same key/value dict as the pandas snippet above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.iter_rows()`

```
dict(df.groupby('key').agg(pl.col('value').sum()).iter_rows())
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Which can also be written using [`GroupBy.sum()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.sum) ref: [@DeanMacGregor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941121/replicating-pandas-to-dict-in-polars#comment133946656_75941329)

```
dict(df.groupby('key').sum().iter_rows())
```

Comment: The second one seems much faster, the first is almost the same speed as pandas

Comment: Ah, good to know, it's also quite a bit of typing. I found `.iter_rows` works too if you'd like to see how it performs.

Comment: Okay, `.iter_rows` is much faster in my local testing, so I've removed the previous suggestions.

Comment: You can just do `df.groupby('key').sum()` if it's a dataframe rather than a lazyframe to cut down on typing.

Comment: Thanks @DeanMacGregor - looks like there is a lazy version too, it would just need a `.collect()` before the `.iter_rows()`

Comment: Nice `.iter_rows()` is even faster than the prior version using `zip`